# Typescript + react-create-app with express problem

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express

I'm new to Typescript, so I created a react-create-app project, the issue I have right know is that I want to connect a server  with express.

The thing is I create a folder -> src/server/server.ts

so, react automatically creates a tsconfig.json which is:

```
{
 "compilerOptions": {
   "target": "es5",
   "lib": [
     "dom",
     "dom.iterable",
     "esnext"
   ],
   "allowJs": true,
   "skipLibCheck": true,
   "esModuleInterop": true,
   "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
   "strict": true,
   "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
   "module": "esnext",
   "moduleResolution": "node",
   "resolveJsonModule": true,
   "isolatedModules": true,
   "noEmit": true,
   "jsx": "react"
 },
 "include": [
   "src"
 ],
 "exclude": ["src/server"]
}
```

I added the exclude part and created other tsconfig file

tsconfig.server.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    /* Basic Options */                 /* Enable incremental compilation */
    "target": "es5",                          /* Specify ECMAScript target version: 'ES3' (default), 'ES5', 'ES2015', 'ES2016', 'ES2017', 'ES2018', 'ES2019', 'ES2020', or 'ESNEXT'. */
    "module": "commonjs",                     /* Specify module code generation: 'none', 'commonjs', 'amd', 'system', 'umd', 'es2015', 'es2020', or 'ESNext'. */                      /* Concatenate and emit output to single file. */
    "outDir": "./build",                        /* Redirect output structure to the directory. */
    "rootDir": "./src/server",                       /* Specify the root directory of input files. Use to control the output directory structure with --outDir. */
    /* Strict Type-Checking Options */
    "strict": true,                           /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */
    "esModuleInterop": true,                  /* Enables emit interoperability between CommonJS and ES Modules via creation of namespace objects for all imports. Implies 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports'. */
    /* Advanced Options */
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true  /* Disallow inconsistently-cased references to the same file. */
  },
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json"
}
```

when I type in the command line tsc I want the server.ts to be compiled in the build folder in the root of my project but nonetheless is not working.

it's simple doesn't do nothing.

do you know what i'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `tsc --project --build` to build, or if you are developing I would recommend you use `tsc --project --watch` which will re-compile every time a file has changed.

Full list of compiler options can be found [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html)

Comment: thanks for the answer, in this case is not working as the problem is that the tsconfig.server.json it doesnt look like is wire up with the tsconfig.json, I do that and it says that it's fine, but it doesnt generate what I need from the server

Comment: Are you trying to use tsconfig.server.json instead of tsconfig.json?

Comment: I'm trying yo use tsconfig.json as a base and tsconfig.server.json as an extension for the server

Comment: I found the solution at the end I had to create a base tsc and the made what you told me, it works !! thank you!!

Comment: I see you're new on SO, when an answer solves your question/issue, you should always accept it to let other people know what worked